# C++ word maker issue

Tags: c++, string, cin

I am currently writing a program that makes a game out of song lyrics using a function that takes a jumble of lyrics and converts it into an array of words. My current issue is that when I run the program with a normal string, it works fine, but when I try to debug the program using cin to save user input to the string, it quits without an error as soon as I enter the user input. I have simplified the program down to just the bare bones of what it actually is so that there is no confusion about where the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <array>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

//function that gets the characters from a string and separates them into words 
//then saves them    in a vector
vector <string> getlyrics(string dat)
{
    //save dat as a new string data
    //get the size of the data string to get number of characters
    string data = dat;
    int siz = data.size();
    //used to keep track of current letter position when creating words
    string letter;
    //used to keep track of previous letter position when creating words
    string prevletter;
    //used to keep track of current word
    string word;
    //creates a vector called lyrics to keep track of lyrics in order
    vector <string> lyrics;

    //for every letter in data string...
    for(int i = 0; i<=siz; i++)
    {
        //set the letter for current place in data string
        letter+=data[i];

        //if we are on the first letter...
        if(i == 0)
        {
            //... then the previous letter is empty
            prevletter = "";
        }
        //otherwise, the previous letter is the previous character in data string
        else
        {
            prevletter += data[i-1];
        }

        //if the letter is not equal to a space or a newline or an empty...
        if(letter != " " && letter != "\n" && letter != "")
        {
            //then add the current letter to the word
            word += data[i];
            //reset the letter
            letter = "";

        }
        //otherwise if the letter is a space or newline
        else if(letter== " " || letter == "\n" || letter == "")
        {
            //if the previous letter not equal to a space or newline
            if(prevletter!=" "||prevletter!="\n")
            {
                //then the word is finished
                //add it to the lyrics vector without adding the new letter to the word
                lyrics.push_back(word);
                //reset the word, letter, and add 1 to the word count
                word = "";
                letter = "";
            }
        }
        //reset the previous letter
        prevletter = "";
    }
    //return the vector lyrics
    return lyrics;
}
int main()
{
    //creates a user input string called text
    string textstr;
    cin>>textstr;
    //runs the string through getlyrics() function and saves it in vector called textvec
    vector <string> textvec = getlyrics(textstr);
    //creates a string array called textarr of equal size to the vector
    string textarr[textvec.size()];
    int i = 0;
    //for each value in the vector, save that value to a corresponding index in textarr
    for(auto c : textvec)
    {
        textarr[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    //print out all values stored in textarr
    //(I can use the size of textvec as the max because textvec and textarr are equally sized)
    for(int k = 0; k<textvec.size(); k++)
    {
        cout<<textarr[k]<<endl;
    }
    //wait for user input
    int x;
    cin>> x;
}
```

Comment: By "debug" you mean in an actual debugger? If so you should be able to step through and see what's going on.

Comment: Can you print out what you `cin`? So right after you `cin` can you `cout` the same string?

Comment: @Jonathan Potter. Yes, I mean in an actual debugger, but for some reason I receive no errors and the program just exits without throwing any exception

Comment: @Jay I tried that but the debugger simply quit without giving me any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fundamental problem is here:

```
string textstr;
cin>>textstr;
```

When you read a string this way, it stops reading input at the first whitespace, so `textstr` will only contain the first "word" you typed<sup>1</sup>. You probably want to use `std::getline` instead.

---

<sup>1. This could be used to write a much simpler version of your `getlyrics` function.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This is not standard C++:

```
string textarr[textvec.size()];
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//             not a compile time constant
```

It's a Variable Length Array (VLA) and you shouldn't do it. That said, you already have a `vector<string>`, why do you need to convert it to a `string[]`? If you really need a `string*` for something you can just use:

```
string* textarr = &textvec[0];    // C++03
string* textarr = textvec.data(); // C++11
```

Comment: I see your point, but I prefer having an array with the same size as the vector just because I am more comfortable using the c++ functions for array in my game and I did it more to see if I could. Also, I am familiar with the concept of pointers but I don't really understand the difference between pointers and arrays in c++. Anyways, I appreciate the input and I will educate myself on pointers soon.